# How to calculate past 1 day interval from current time in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlalchemy

I want be able to filter `sqlalchemy` query by checking if `datetime` column is above some date which is 1 day before now().

Any ideas what is the correct syntax to do so?

**Note**:

1 .sqlalchemy query should look something like that:
`one_day_interval_before = ?
result = session.query(People).filter(People.registered_at>= one_day_interval_before).all()`

2. datetime retrived in python should be able to be compared to mysql datetime field, in format (year-month-day hour:minutes:seconds)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For time intervals in Python use `datetime.timedelta`. A day before now would be then:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

one_day_interval_before = datetime.now() - timedelta(days=1)
```

Answer (score 6):

you can also use `func` which includes most sql functions

```
from sqlalchemy import func
result = session.query(People)\
    .filter(People.registered_at>= func.ADDDATE(func.NOW(), -1)).all()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
datetime.datetime.strftime(datetime.datetime.now()-datetime.timedelta(1),'%Y-%m-%d')
```